# In Corda, how can I query the vault for all states recorded after a specific time?

Tags: corda

I want to retrieve all the states my node has recorded after time `x`. How can I get a stream of all the states recorded by my node since that time?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example RPC client that streams back all the states stored by the node after time `x`:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // Getting an RPC connection to the node.
    require(args.size == 2) { "Usage: ExampleClientRPC <node address> <time>" }
    val nodeAddress = NetworkHostAndPort.parse(args[0])
    val client = CordaRPCClient(nodeAddress)
    val rpcOps = client.start("user1", "test").proxy

    val startTime = Instant.parse(args[2])

    val queryAfterTimeExpression = TimeCondition(
            RECORDED, BinaryComparison(GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, startTime))
    val queryAfterTimeCriteria = VaultQueryCriteria(
            status = Vault.StateStatus.ALL,
            timeCondition = queryAfterTimeExpression)
    val queryAfterTimeResults = rpcOps.vaultTrackBy<ContractState>(queryAfterTimeCriteria)
    val afterTimeStates = queryAfterTimeResults.updates
}
```